# Accessing view helper methods from Capybara rquest specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I've got the view helper method in my application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def formatted_something(something)
   "Hello, #{something}"
 end
end
```

I want to access that method in my request spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "something" do
  include RequestSpecHelper

  it "should display blogs list" do
    visit something_url
    page.should have_content formatted_something(@something.something)
  end
end
```

It couldn't  find **formatted_something** method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to include the relevant helper module in your `describe` block, and it will be available in all nested specs:

```
describe "something" do
  include RequestSpecHelper
  include ApplicationHelper

  ...
end
```